# Returning Random.randint

Tags: python-3.x

Creating a luck function to return random numbers to be called later on. This code works but is it the most efficient way to go about it?

```
import random

def luck_question():
   luck = input("What will you do --> ")
   if luck in "a":
       print("Well done")
       choice = random.randint(1, 50)
       return choice
   elif luck in "b":
       print("Nice Job")
       choice = random.randint(1, 50)
   elif luck in "c":
       print("I see now")
       choice = random.randint(1, 50)
luck = luck_question()
print(f"{luck}")
```

Comment: If it works then it should be on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) not SO. Also always make sure to **properly** indent your code when you ask a question. Don't just indent it till it makes a code block.

Comment: Off the bat you should use `==` not `in` and your `choice` should be pulled out of the if statements since you do the same thing for each one. Your also missing a few returns.

Comment: Just curious, why the == instead of in? Is it a readability issue?

Sorry about the indention issue - still learning how to use this website appropriately.

Comment: What's wrong with the indention of the code above? To me it matches how the code is written in the editor. How do I add code to these comments as well?

Comment: 1) I reindented your code. Please look at the edit history (click the link above my name right below your question "edited x mins ago"). 2) `in` and `==` do two different things. If I input `abc` then `if 'a' in luck` will be `True` where as `==` will be `False`.

Comment: OH I see the issue you're referring to now. Thanks for that. I get what you mean regarding the in and ==. I also did `choice = random.randit(1, 50)` at the top and now just do `choice` in the if statements to call it.

Comment: Add you desired output for given inputs (some test cases) and I can show you a much cleaner way to write this.

Comment: What's the cleaner way?

Comment: I need to know your desired output first. Your function just prints different things but does the same `random.choice` call for each one.

Comment: I just wanted it to do a random number stored to choice, regardless of which if statement gets pulled.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have above can be written shorter and cleaner using a `dict` for your outputs and just return the random int.

```
import random

def luck_question():
   luck = input("What will you do --> ")

   # This maps the user input `luck` to
   # what should be printed.
   messages_for_inputs = {
       'a': 'Well done',
       'b': 'Nice Job',
       'c': 'I see now',
   }
   # The get call on a dictionary will try to get
   # the desired key (the first argument) and if the
   # key is not found it will return the default (second argument).
   print(messages_for_inputs.get(luck, 'unknown luck'))
   return random.randint(1, 50)

luck = luck_question()
print(f"{luck}")
```

The `dict` also makes it a lot easier for you to add other user inputs.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your help! I haven't learned about dictionaries yet, so this is neat.